# Acceder a elementos del layout tras el evento onMarkerClick

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-asynctask

Estoy atascado en el desarrollo de mi aplicación y no encuentro nada que me solucione el problema.

Una vez que el evento `onMarkerClick` se produce, tras haberse producido antes una llamada asíncrona. Cuando salta el evento de clickmarker no puedo acceder a dos elementos de layout que están invisibles para hacerlos visibles.

No sé si es porque ese evento se ejecuta en el contexto de la tarea asíncrona, y he leído que esas tareas no pueden modificar elementos del layout o por qué es. Pero si en cambio establezco un botón normal en la pantalla y lo pincho, sí que funciona.

Aquí os dejo el código de la actividad y xml.

```
public class MainActivityDos extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    // variables nuevas
    private Button url_ruta;

    //hasta aquí variables nuevas

    private String origin;
    private String destination;
    private String point1;
    private String point2;

    //array de coordenadas

    private String coordiantes;
    private int n_points;
    private String query;

    private DownloadTask downloadTask;

    private LinearLayout layoutBar, layoutButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_dos);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        layoutBar = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.progressBarLayout);
        layoutButton = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonsAudio);


        url_ruta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.urlRuta);
        url_ruta.setOnClickListener(this);

        //coger lo que se envía en el intent;

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); // estoy puede estar vacío

        if(bundle != null){
            //String rutaUrl = bundle.get("URL_RUTA").toString();

            coordiantes = (bundle.get("COORDINATES").toString());
            query = (bundle.get("QUERY").toString());
            n_points = Integer.parseInt(bundle.get("POINTS").toString());

            url_ruta.setText(query);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng OriginPoint = new LatLng(40.408272, -3.694506);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(OriginPoint, 16));
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        sendRequest();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

        if(marker.getTitle().equals("punto1")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hola" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            downloadTask.cancel(true);
            //cambiarLayout();
             layoutButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //this is no working.
             layoutBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        return false;
    }


    public void sendRequest(){

        try{
            //String url = createUrl();

            downloadTask = new DownloadTask(mMap,coordiantes);

            downloadTask.execute(query);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        layoutButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // this is working
        layoutBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<!--<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ivan.myapplicationmaps.MapsActivity" />-->
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_dos"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.ivan.myapplicationmaps.MainActivityDos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter destination address"
        android:id="@+id/urlRuta" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonsAudio"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:background="@color/wallet_bright_foreground_disabled_holo_light"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsAudio"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/wallet_bright_foreground_disabled_holo_light"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <Button
            android:text="Play"
            android:id="@+id/buttonFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Museo reina sofia y atocha refe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: que hace o debe hacer la aplicación??...  para entender mejor

Comment: debes cambiar         googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
por mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

Comment: Mil gracias, era justo eso. Te juro que lo había dado mil vueltas puff, para ver eso. Pues estoy haciendo una aplicación que pregunta a la api directions de google y te devuelve una ruta con puntos y cuando pinchara a la chincheta debería sacar los linearlayout donde tengo una barra de progreso y un botón de audio.

Comment: @Ivan trata lo que pongo en mi respuesta para habilitar correctamente el click, me comentas resultados.

Comment: @Ivan No te preocupes, a todos se nos pasa. Dale la respuesta correcta a Elenasys para que ayuda a futuros usuarios

Answer (score 1):

Al recibir la instancia de `GoogleMap` es asignada a la variable `mMap`, en la cual asignas mover la cámara y habilitar la localización, pero el `ClickListener` del marcador lo estas asignando a la instancia original `googleMap` , cambia a :

```
 //googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
```

Comment: gracias Elena, con eso funciona bien. Me habéis sacado de un apuro porque de verdad que no veía el error.

Comment: @Ivan si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, sería recomendable que la **aceptes**, haciendo click en el **✓** a la izquierda de la misma. No se descuenta nada por eso (todo lo contrario, ambos ganan reputación).